# CSS expanding menu collapses on hover in IE 11

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-11

I'm not fond of social media "Like" buttons, so I'm trying to come up with a minimalist approach of displaying them on my pages in a way that they are not as intrusive and flow with my site's design.  I came across the website jackthreads.com and liked the way they use a slide-in/slide-out mouseover feature to display their like buttons.  So, not surprisingly, I'm trying to replicate their idea on my site.

Basically I have an icon for each major social media network (Facebook, G+, and Twitter).  When you hover your mouse cursor over an icon (i.e. facebook), a like button will replace the icon by sliding in from the left, giving the visitor the opportunity to "Like" the page.  Naturally, the "Like" button will slide out of view when their mouse cursor moves away from the hover area.

The good news is, I have it working perfectly for Chrome, Safari, and Firefox.  Unfortunately IE is giving me a headache.

Here's what happens in IE:

- You hover your cursor over the icon and the like button slides into view
- As soon as you move your cursor to click "like", the menu starts to open/collapse rapidly and eventually the button slides out of view.

**TLDR:** I can't tell IE to keep the menu open when a mouse cursor is over it.

Having social media on my site isn't a huge priority, so originally I tried disabling the feature for all IE browsers...but IE 11 doesn't support browser detection tags.  So after an hour of tinkering with the code to get it to work on IE 11, I figured my best chance of solving this issue would be to ask the experts here.

**JSFiddle** - I took the liberty of writing a very crude example on jsfiddle.  The menu will stay open when you hover over the like button in all browsers, except for IE: http://jsfiddle.net/V67Mt/3/

Basically, I'm using CSS transitions to slide the buttons in and out of DIV containers.  I'm not sure if the solution involves using jQuery in combination with CSS3 or if it can be done solely with CSS3, but whatever works is fine for me.

HTML

```
 <div id="social_media">
 <ul>
 <li id="facebook">
     <div id="facebook_like">
         <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false">
         </div>
     </div>
 </li>
</ul>
</div>

<!-- Facebook Code-->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

CSS

```
#social_media{
display:inline-block;
    background-color:#c0c0c0;
float:left;
text-align:left;
color:#000;
}
#social_media li{
list-style:none;
display:inline-block;
}
#facebook {
display:block;
width:60px;
height:20px;
-webkit-transition: width 1s, background-image 1s ease-out;
-moz-transition:width 1s, background-image 1s ease-out;
-ms-transition:width 1s, background-image 1s ease-out;
-o-transition:width 1s, background-image 1s ease-out;
transition:width 1s, background-image 1s ease-out;
    position:relative;
overflow:hidden;
}
#facebook:after{
    content: "TEST";
    padding-left:12px;
}
#facebook:hover{
width:100px;
}
#facebook:hover #facebook_like{
margin-left:10px;
width:100px;
display:inline-block;
overflow:visible;
}

#facebook_like{
display:inline-block;
margin-left:-100px;
-webkit-transition: margin-left 1s;
-moz-transition:margin-left 1s;
-ms-transition:margin-left 1s;
-o-transition:margin-left 1s;
transition:margin-left 1s;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: This one's stumping me, but I'm partly wondering whether Facebook's iframe is interfering - that little Like button is an entirely separate HTML document.

Comment: @Katana314 - The solution is eluding me as well.  It does the same thing with the G+ code, but it works if I use my own code (i.e. create my own DIV). I'm thinking about spending my time searching for a method to block all IE browsers, but that's not really a good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery can sort this out. just by adding couple of hovering behaviour lines

```
$("#facebook").hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass("active");
    },function(){
        $(this).removeClass("active");
    })
```

and changing :hover property to a class.

```
#facebook.active{
width:100px;
}
#facebook.active #facebook_like{
margin-left:10px;
    width:100px;
}
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/V67Mt/6/)